# custom Django Rest Framework serializer to look up field for POST request

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer and I want it to get a field from another model for POST requests. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do (code taken from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h48Fxecu7EY)

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_username_from_author_table')
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'author_id', 'username']

    def get_username_from_author_table(self, author_id):
        return Author.objects.get(id=author_id).username
```

And my BlogPost model has the following fields: title, username.

Is it possible to create this serializer for a POST request? I haven't been able to get it to work, and I'm seeing that SerializerMethodField is only for GET requests in other posts.

Comment: what fields you want to use in post request to create `BlogPost` object?